# No sound on my Dell Inspiron 5559

Tags: sound, dell

Using Ubuntu 16.04 and having Dell Inspiron 5559 with i3

My sound initially working fine after installation. Now **aplay -l** showing "no soundcards found..."

Comment: if you have dualboot , do a real shutdown from windows

Comment: Don't have dual boot

Comment: Alexander, stop editing for points. Don't waste my time